# creating an XML attribute from var in dataweave 2.0

Tags: mule, dataweave, anypoint-studio, mule4

I have a JSON input:

```
{
  abc: "",
  def: "hello"

}
```

I want to make this blank element as nillable in XML i.e. . I am using the below dataweave code:

```
%dw 2,0
output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
var makeNil= (in) ->
in match {
case is Array -> in map makeNil($)
case is Object -> in mapObject (
if ( ($) == "")
  ($$) @(xsi#'nil':true): {}
else ($$): makeNil($)
)
else -> in
}
---
makeNil(payload)
```

I am not able to create an attribute using @(xsi#'nil':true) for key($$). Please help me

Comment: There are some errors that need to be fixed before the script even executes: the keys in the JSON payload miss quotes, it is an invalid JSON. The version separator is a dot, not a comma, and the xsi namespace is not defined.
What is the root element of the output? Provide an example of the expected output, and the actual results or error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving the errors that I mentioned in my comment, adding a root element works. Remember that XML unlike JSON requires a root element.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml skipNullOn="everywhere"
ns xsi http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance
var makeNil= (in) ->
    in match {
        case is Array -> in map makeNil($)
        case is Object -> in mapObject (
            if ( ($) == "")
                ($$) @(xsi#'nil':true): {}
            else ($$): makeNil($)
        )
        else -> in
    }
---
top: makeNil(payload)
```

input:

```
{
  "abc": "",
  "def": "hello"
}
```

output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<top>
  <abc xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
  <def>hello</def>
</top>
```